# JMeter Beanshell Error handling using try/catch

Tags: error-handling, jmeter, try-catch, beanshell

I'm trying to use beanshell try catch scripting but I struggle with it. so few questions:

Why when I try to run the following code I receive error, **and not the catch statement "Error in beanshell?**

```
String str = "a";
try {
    log.info(str)
}

catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Error in beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Error:

```
2016/12/14 10:26:33 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: ``String str = "a"; try {    log.info(str) }  catch (Exception ex) {     log.error("Err . . . '' Encountered "}" at line 4, column 1.

2016/12/14 10:26:33 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``String str = "a"; try {    log.info(str) }  catch (Exception ex) {     log.error("Err . . . '' Encountered "}" at line 4, column 1.
```

Secondly, When I run this code:

```
try {
    String str = "a";
    log.info(str)
}

catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Error in beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

I get this error:

```
2016/12/14 10:27:25 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of: ``try {  String str = "a";   log.info(str) }  catch (Exception ex) {     log.error("Er . . . '' Encountered "}" at line 4, column 1.

2016/12/14 10:27:25 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``try {  String str = "a";   log.info(str) }  catch (Exception ex) {     log.error("Er . . . '' Encountered "}" at line 4, column 1.
```

Same, I don't understand why the Catch hasn't come in play.
Also - what are is the difference between Catch Exception/Throwable/EvalError, etc?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are missing semicolon after `log.info(str)` so you code needs to be:

```
String str = "a";
try {
    log.info(str);//<-- this semicolon is VERY important
}

catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Error in beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

Beanshell [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) won't help if your code is not valid (cannot be properly evaluated due to syntax error or typo)

One more tip: you can get extra logging output by adding [debug()](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) command to the beginning of your Beanshell script.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on Beanshell scripting in Jmeter

Comment: How to use the `debug()`? I just add it in the beggining of the script? on the link you added I didn't find guide of using it.

Comment: yes, if you add this directive in the beginning of the script you will see a lot of output in STDOUT (console window where you launched JMeter from)

Comment: And if I'm still on the debuging proccess of my project and use the GUI? Where should I see it?

Answer (score 1):

you are playing with syntax (missing `;`), so Java interpreter exists. Exception Handling is not intended for capturing syntax errors.

---

try the following example which throws `ArithmeticException` :

```
import java.lang.ArithmeticException;

try {
    int i = 1/0;
} catch ( ArithmeticException e ) {
    log.info( "print" + e );
}
```

Reference:

1. http://www.beanshell.org/manual/syntax.html

Comment: So how can I find Syntax errors in my BeanShell code when I write my script? I tried adding the ArithmeticException you said and removing the ";" from the int i = 1/0 but the ArithmeticException didn't raise

Comment: I don't know if we can handle syntax errors as Exceptions. above code is an example for exception handling where you perform `division by 0` which raises `ArithmeticException`. FYI, no one uses exception handling for the purpose of syntax errors. the example works with valid syntax (add `;`) so, correct the syntax and try, you will see the `Arithmetic Exception` will be shown as just `info` instead of `BeanShell Error`